# What is proper way to insert and query data in pinecone vector database?

Tags: embedding, openai-api, vector-database

I have a json data in format:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Pocketbase",
    "description": "Some description text",
    "product_url": "https://pocketbase.io",
    "github_url": "https://github.com/pocketbase/pocketbase",
    "more_details": "raw text of features, uses cases etc.",
    "open_source": true,
    "expand": { type: [{}] }
  }
]
```

I am converting it to following text for save in pinecone:

```js
const tagList = data.expand.type.map(t => t.name);

let textTempalte = `Name of software: ${data.name}
Description: ${data.description}
Places it will be helpful: ${tagList.join(',')}
Is this project open source: ${data.open_source ? "Yes" : "No"}`;

if (data.more_detail.length > 0) {
  textTempalte = textTempalte.concat(`\nMore detail: ${tech.more_detail}`);
}
if (data.product_url.length > 0) {
  textTempalte = textTempalte.concat(`\nProduct homepage: ${tech.product_url}`);
}
if (data.github_url.length > 0) {
  textTempalte = textTempalte.concat(`\nGithub link: ${tech.github_url}`);
}
```

Using model `text-embedding-ada-002` I am creating embeddings and adding those embeddings for each data in response to an index in pinecone db.

When I am making query with input such as "Realtime database" which is there in `description` and `more_detail`, matches return as 0 from pinecone.

```js
// Create embeding
const oaiResponse = await openai.createEmbedding({
  model: "text-embedding-ada-002",
  input: "realtime database",
});
const vector: QueryRequest = {
  topK: 10,
  vector: oaiResponse.data.data[0].embedding,
  includeMetadata: true,
  namespace: 'Default Project',
};

const resp = await index.query({
  queryRequest: vector,
});

console.log(resp.mactches.length); // 0
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

This is an async request, better to use "then" method to wait for the response

```
// Create embedding
    await openai.createEmbedding({
      model: "text-embedding-ada-002",
      input: "realtime database",
    })
    .then(async(oaiResponse)=> {
       const vector: QueryRequest = {
       topK: 10,
       vector: oaiResponse.data.data[0].embedding,
       includeMetadata: true,
       namespace: 'Default Project',
      };
    
      const resp = await index.query({
        queryRequest: vector,
      });
    })
    .then(console.log(resp.mactches.length);)
```